# Python lookup key/Values between list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to lookup two list of dictionaries based on matching keys. If the keys and values match between any dictionaries, I want to copy key value pairs from second dictionary to the first one and return it as an output. But if no match is found, the dictionary should be returned as reject. Below is an example of what I want to do and what I have coded. I am able to get my results but I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
input_list =  [{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':3},
               {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c':6},
               {'a':7, 'b': 8, 'c':9}]

ref_list =    [{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'd':3, 'e': 10},
               {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'd':6, 'e': 11}]

matching_cols = ['a','b']
copy_over_cols = ['d','e']

expected_output_list = [{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':3, 'd':3, 'e':10,},
                        {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c':6, 'd':6, 'e':11,}]

expected_reject_list = [{'a':7, 'b': 8, 'c':9}]

#What I have coded so far

def lookup_dict(input_list,ref_list,matching_cols,copy_over_cols):
    output_list = []
    reject_list = []
    for input_dict in input_list:
        match_cols_dict = dict(tuple((col,input_dict[col]) for col in matching_cols))
        matched = False
        copy_over_items = {}
        for ref_dict in ref_list:
            check_cols_dict = dict(tuple((col,ref_dict[col]) for col in matching_cols))
            if match_cols_dict == check_cols_dict:
                matched = True
                copy_over_items = dict((tuple((col,ref_dict[col]) for col in copy_over_cols)))
                break
        if matched == True:
            input_dict.update(copy_over_items)
            output_list.append(input_dict)
        else:
            reject_list.append(input_dict)
    return output_list, reject_list

output_list, reject_list = lookup_dict(input_list,ref_list,matching_cols,copy_over_cols)
print("output - ", output_list, "reject - ", reject_list)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
output_list = list()
reject_list = list()

for i in input_list:
    matches = [d for d in ref_list if all(i[c]==d[c] for c in matching_cols)]
    if len(matches)>0:
        j = matches[0]
        output_list.append({**i, **{k: j[k] for k in copy_over_cols}})
    else:
        reject_list.append(i)

>>> output_list
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 3, 'e': 10},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 11}]

>>> reject_list
[{'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]
```